Use Clipboard between Mac and Microsoft Remote Desktop
Unfortunately, I cannot share my clipboard between a Mac accessing a remote Windows Workspace: I have a Mac running macOS 14.5 and Microsoft Remote Desktop 10.9.9. From this setup I access a remote Workspace with Windows 11 22H2.
In the Remote Desktop app Clipboard Mode is Disabled and greyed out so that I cannot change it. I was hoping killing and running rdpclip.exe (as described here for example Cannot share clipboard when using Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection to Windows7) would get the clipboard working but it doesn’t.
Any ideas how I could get this working between machines?
Thank you!

Is the Windows computer a work machine? If that's the case, copy/paste could be disabled using Group Policy (see https://superuser.com/a/303214) and there's nothing you can do about it.
